C# NetworkCredentials with Domain \ Username error
I am working on an ASP.NET app on the .NET Framework 3.5.
I am sending an email using
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

To set the credentials, I am doing this:
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

But I have problems to access from outside the server. I am trying to set the DOMAIN like this
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"DOMAIN\" + USERNAME, PASSWORD);

but @"DOMAIN\" + USERNAME translates to  "DOMAIN\\" + USERNAME and it does not work.
Is there a way to set the domain? Or make @"DOMAIN" to not be replaced with "DOMAIN\" ?
Thanks

Are you sure it is a credentials issue?  Does code work if you use the default credentials?  Do you have the permissions on the network (local, remote, and Mail Server) to impersonate another user?

"is translate it to "DOMAIN\" + USERNAME" no that's just the way it's showing n the debugger. What is DOMAIN is it actually an AD domain, and is USERNAME part of that domain?
